# Trying to replicate C# hashing in Perl (on Linux)

Tags: c#, perl

I'm not coming up with the same values (using a known password).

I suspect it may be something having to do with encodings, but all the things I've tried haven't worked thus far:

windows code (c#?):

```
private static string EncodePassword(string password, string salt)
{
    string encodedPassword = password;
    HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1 { Key = Convert.FromBase64String(salt) };
    encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));

    return encodedPassword;
}
```

perl code run on linux:

```
use Modern::Perl '2015';
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha1 hmac_sha1_base64);
use MIME::Base64 qw(decode_base64 encode_base64);
use Unicode::String qw(utf16be utf16le);

say encode_base64(hmac_sha1($password, decode_base64($salt)));
# (or, equivalently)
say hmac_sha1_base64($password, decode_base64($salt));

my $le16 = utf16le($password);
my $be16 = utf16be($password);
say "ok, try utf-16 (le, then be)...";
say encode_base64(hmac_sha1($le16, decode_base64($salt)));
say encode_base64(hmac_sha1($be16, decode_base64($salt)));

# try reversing the hmac output?                                                                                                                                          
my $hmac_bytes = hmac_sha1($password, decode_base64($salt));
my $rev_bytes = reverse $hmac_bytes;
say encode_base64($rev_bytes);
```

Comment: I know that the RSACryptoServiceProvider in C# emits bytes in reverse order from any other library.  It's possible the HMCASHA1 has does as well.

Comment: that seems confusing. I'll post above (where the formatting will be better) what I tried to test this, which didn't seem to get me there, but again not sure if I'm handling the bytes correctly.

Comment: why is my question being down-voted? Is there something I need to include? Did I mis-state something? I am completely baffled.

Comment: @DevinCeartas I can't speak for the people who down-voted your question, but you might want to make the title more specific. Also, it might help to get to the point more quickly and be more obvious about what the question is. Finally, if you have any sample output to compare, that could also be helpful.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've tried to make the title more descriptive and cut out most of my preamble. Unfortunately I have only real values (real passwords and salt) for the windows code, so I'm not sure it would be wise to publish that output. It's base64 encoded SHA1 hashes, so it all looks a bit like wjA5+piE4zXBHlMReIBt3J4iLeo=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original C# code, in this line:

```
encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
```

a call to `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` transforms the password to a byte array via a `UTF-16LE` encoder.

You have to do the same transformation to get the same hash in Perl:

```
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha1);
use MIME::Base64 qw(decode_base64 encode_base64);
use Encode qw(encode);

$utf16LEPassword = encode("UTF-16LE", $password);
print encode_base64(hmac_sha1($utf16LEPassword, decode_base64($salt)));
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks. encodings are frustrating for me; thanks for helping me learn.